# How to Order the Results of a Union Query By Which Of The Two Queries Comes From?

Tags: sql

basically I want this:

```
    SELECT column FROM Table Where column LIKE "%interesting%"
    UNION
    SELECT column FROM Table 
    ORDER BY "the interesting results first, the fillers second."
```

I do this in case the interesting results are few, so that I fill them with random ones.

Answer (score 3):

You simply want an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT column
FROM Table 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN column LIKE '%interesting%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END);
```